# highcharts exporting - Java approach

Tags: highcharts

I'm using the new Java based export server to convert an input JSON to SVG by sending POST requests to the server.

Initially I did some testing on my local machine by running jetty and I was able to send a POST request to localhost:8080/export and get back the SVG.

I have now built the was file and have deployed it on a Tomcat server, the export server is running on port 8080. I can bring up the demo page (http://:8080/highcharts-export-web), but when I click on "Generate Image" or send a POST request thru a client I see a msg "Sorry, the server is handling too many requests at the moment. Please try again."

I tried debugging remotely and saw a Pool exception in Java, can you please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong. Below is my app-convert.properties

```
#### phantomjs properties ####

# the host and port phantomjs listens to
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 7777

# location of the phantomjs executable, could be for example /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
exec = /usr/bin/phantomjs

# name of the convert script used by phantomjs
script = highcharts-convert.js

#### connect properties used to connect with phantomjs running as HTTP-server ####
# all values in milliseconds

# specifies the timeout when reading from phantomjs when a connection is established
readTimeout = 6000

# timeout to be used when opening a communications link to the phantomjs server
connectTimeout = 500

# the whole request to the phantomjs server is scheduled, max timeout can last to this      value. This is because in java you can't rely on the above two timeouts.
maxTimeout = 6500

#### Pool properties ####

# number of phantomjs servers you can run in the pool.
poolSize = 2

# The pool is implemented as a BlockingQueue. When asking for a phantom server  connection and nothing is available, it waits for the number of milliseconds defined by maxWait
maxWait = 500
```

Answer (score 0):

When having problems while using the export-server, the first thing you could do is to enable logging Debug messages. This can give you a clue of what's going wrong. To enable Debug messages, uncomment these lines in highcharts-export/highcharts-export-web/src/main/resources/log4j.properties

```
# Debug specific class
log4j.logger.services=DEBUG
log4j.logger.converter=DEBUG
log4j.logger.exporter=DEBUG
log4j.logger.pool=DEBUG
```

Start the application server and look for the commando's which are used to start phantomjs. See debug statement on line 53 in file Server.java

Can you start a phantomjs server with this commando?

Comment: I figured it out, phantomJS was not running correctly. I had the server running on CentOS and copied phantomJS to /usr/local/bin, but doing this is not sufficient on CentOS, you have to install 2 additional packages. I did a sudo yum install freetype and sudo yum install fontconfig and viola it started working.